# How to read multiple files in parallel

Tags: go, synchronization, channel

I would like to read multiple files in parallel, but I get a deadlock.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var dirname = "."

    res := make(chan string)

    dir, _ := os.Open(dirname)
    files, _ := dir.ReadDir(10)

    filecnt := 0
    for _, file := range files {
        var idx = strings.Index(file.Name(), "input_")
        if idx == 0 {
            filecnt++
            go readFile(dirname+"/"+file.Name(), res)
        }
    }

    donecnt := 0
    for donecnt < filecnt {
        for s := range res {
            if s == "" {
                donecnt++
            }
        }
    }

    close(res)
}

func readFile(filename string, res chan string) {
    file, _ := os.Open(filename)
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        res <- scanner.Text()
    }

    res <- ""
}
```

It blocks at `range res` because this waits until the channel get's closed. How can I close the channel after reading all files? Are there better approaches?

Comment: make `Buffered Channels` (https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Golang's [WaitGroups](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups) to achieve this more efficiently.

Here's how same code can be written using WaitGroups:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    var dirname = "."

    dir, _ := os.Open(dirname)
    files, _ := dir.ReadDir(10)

    for _, file := range files {
        var idx = strings.Index(file.Name(), "input_")
        if idx == 0 {
            wg.Add(1)
            go readFile(dirname+"/"+file.Name(), res)
        }
    }

    // Wait for all goroutines to signal they are done.
    wg.Wait()
}

func readFile(filename string, res chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // Your logic to read file.
}
```